# Simple form post receiving Unauthorized

Tags: scala, playframework

Trying to do a simple form post using Scala Play, getting Unauthorized error.

Here is my `routes` file:

```
POST     /receiveForm              controllers.HomeController.receiveForm
```

Here is my `HomeController.scala` file:

```
def receiveForm = Action { implicit request =>
    println("receiveForm method")
    Ok(views.html.index())
}
```

Here is my `index.scala.html`:

```
@helper.form(routes.HomeController.receiveForm()) {
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
}
```

Looked into CSRF but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed get an `Unauthorized` response from play's CSRF filter if the CSRF token is not found or invalid.

Did you enable the CSRF filter as described [here](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaCsrf#Applying-a-global-CSRF-filter)? I'm assuming you did. Which would then confirm that you are getting this error because you do not post the expected CSRF token. Here's how you should modify your form in order to include the needed token in the post's query string:

```
@import helper._

@form(CSRF(routes.HomeController.receiveForm())) {
  <input type="submit" name="submit" />
}
```

I'm also assuming you initially display the form through a `GET` request. This is needed in order to create the initial token, as described [here](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaCsrf#Adding-a-CSRF-token-to-the-session). The rest should be left as is.

For other ways to add the token to the form (e.g., as an input field), see https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaCsrf#Getting-the-current-token.